# Parsing: "This judge's conclusion" -- "this judge," "this conclusion," either?

Tags: possessives, syntactic-analysis, demonstratives

What is the normal way to parse the following types of phrases?

A. [this X]'s Y

or

B. this [X's Y]

> This man's opinion
>
> This girl's idea
>
> This judge's conclusion
>
> This politician's position

I feel that A is by far more natural, and B would be quite odd, but I'm looking for confirmation and explanation, because I have been told, to my surprise, that parsing as B is perfectly normal.

Is A or B more natural?

If so, why? Syntax?

Are there cases when B is the proper parsing? In what types of cases?

Comment: *This carpenter's square, this farmer's market, this baker's dozen, this driver's license, this ship's chronometer.* Or is that cheating?

Comment: Define *natural*. Primarily opinion-based. They mean different things, and both interpretations are possible. Context, context, context,...

Answer (score 3):

What a wonderful question! I had fun considering the possibilities. I think you're right; for the most part, *This X's Y* would be parsed as *[This X]'s Y* rather than *This [X's Y]*.

It comes down to semantics. The demonstrative **this** is used to mark out the noun referred to. Typically, that noun immediately follows the demonstrative. So *This judge's ruling* gets understood as:

> The ruling of this judge

and not as:

> This ruling of the judge.

The only exceptions I can think of are compound nouns: *This fool's errand* would not usually be parsed as

> The errand of this fool.

Or take this sentence:

> This gentlemen's washroom needs cleaning.

Here, the *this* clearly refers to the entity *gentlemen's washroom*.

> The washroom of this gentlemen

wouldn't even be grammatical. But aside from the case of such noun phrases (*Alzheimer's patient*, *Hobson's choice*), it seems natural to parse *This X's Y* as being *[This X]'s Y* and not *This [X's Y]*.

I'm citing no sources, but this was too long to post as a comment.